# How do I prevent custom UITableViewCells from flashing white on deselecting?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

I have a custom UITableViewCell which changes color based on which row it is in:

`TableViewController.m`

```
- (void)willDisplayCell:(GSRSongCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        [cell lighten];
    } else {
        [cell darken];
    }
}
```

`CustomTableViewCell.m`

```
- (void)lighten
{
    self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.primaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
- (void)darken
{
    UIColor *darkColor = [UIColor colorWithR:241 G:241 B:241 A:1];
    self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = darkColor;
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = darkColor;
    self.primaryLabel.backgroundColor = darkColor;
    self.secondaryLabel.backgroundColor = darkColor;
}
```

However, when I call `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:YES`, the animation fades to a white color in cells where the `selectedBackgroundColor` should be darker.

I then realised that the deselection animation has nothing to do with the `selectedBackgroundColor`; in fact, the deselection animation is actually based on the `tableView.backgroundColor` property!

How can I override the deselection animation to fade to the background color of my cells?

Comment: I have also tried setting the tableView.backgroundColor to [UIColor clearColor] - this has no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It actually animates back to cell background color so you will have to set it too

Add this line in lighten method

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and this in darken method

```
self.backgroundColor = darkColor;
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just set the cell selection to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone in the UIBuilder or in code:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Comment: For me in Swift I have 'cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None'