# How to stop UITableViewCell flashing to white when deselecting?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the common pattern of a `UITableView` with a secondary view controller which gets pushed over the top when a row is selected. To give the user some context when they dismiss the second view controller and return to the tableview, that first view controller has this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: index, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

That results in this unintended and jarring transition in which the cell being deselected fades it's background away, before snapping back to normal :

[image: jarring animation]

My expectation was that it would transition from the partially subdued state selection left it in directly back to the normal, dark state.

(The cell is very much a work-in-progress - it's far from finished)

Following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882400/how-do-i-prevent-custom-uitableviewcells-from-flashing-white-on-deselecting) isn't really an option as I do want to preserve the context hint and the cell as a whole should continue to have a white background.

In response to Rico's question, the cell is created as a `.swift` and `.xib` pair, the hierarchy of views being:

[image: Interface Builder view hierarchy]

The Swift does very little - sets `.textInsets` on the two labels, draws the disclosure indicator in the button.

Comment: How you create the cell?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio See updates to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because the default implementation of `setSelected` removes the background color of all subviews of the cell. What you can do is override `setSelected` and/or `setHighlighted` and update the cell yourself.

This also allows you to create a custom look for selected cells.

Example that uses a red background when selected, and white when not selected:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let animationDuration = animated ? 0.3 : 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
      self.backgroundColor = highlighted ? UIColor.red : UIColor.white
    }
  }
```

Comment: That sounds very promising - I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. At least, nothing that didn't cause the cell shadows to flicker.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `deselecting` the `row` in `viewWillAppear(_:)`, call `deselectRow(at:animated:)` inside the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` method, i.e

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    //Your rest of the code...
}
```

**Edit-1:**

In `viewWillAppear(_:)`, you need to `deselect` the `cell` in `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)` with `animation` set to `true` in `deselectRow(at:animated:)`, i.e.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That eliminates the jarring flash, but it also removes the helpful contextual reminder of "this is the cell you just edited" when the secondary view controller is popped.

Comment: Didn't get you. Kindly clarify.

Comment: I just moved your code from `viewWillAppear(_:)` to `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`. What you're saying might be a different requirement.

Comment: To see the normal behaviour, you can use Mail.app on iPhone. From the Mailboxes view, tap a mailbox. It highlights and shows you the messages in it. When you come back, the highlight is still there and fades away *at that moment*. This lets you see "I was just looking at a bunch of messages, they are in *that* mailbox". That's the default behaviour, and it's what I'm trying to preserve, but the default highlighting looks bad in my case.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I think this will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: The flash-to-white comes from the default behaviour of `setSelected` (see the discussion section of the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623255-setselected]). Overrides of that still need to call `super.setSelected` (https://medium.com/@imho_ios/why-uitableviewcell-highlight-and-selection-styling-are-such-a-mystery-1ae1599e660a), but there are negative consequences to that. I can make the title behave, but the shadow is still removed and restored. tl;dr I think there are unavoidable interactions.